# use libraries in Scala

Tags: scala, http, scala-dispatch

I'm a bit of a noob to Scala at the moment and I'm messing about making little toy projects.

One of the things I want to do is a bit of web page scraping, a quick google search suggested using the `dispatch` package available from here http://dispatch.databinder.net/Download

The thing is I don't know where to put this package once downloaded and I don't know where Scala needs it to be for me to reference it.

I tried looking for it using `sbaz available` but it doesn't seem to be there either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file) to the [classpath](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166#Execute%20it%20!):

```
scala -classpath <...>.jar
```

,or download [SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), [Maven](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/index.html), any other build tool that can manage dependencies.
E.g., in SBT you can simply [put all the JARs you need under the /lib folder](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement) to get them automatically added to the classpath.

Comment: Or, in fact, on SBT you can specify the library as a project dependency, and not worry about it anymore.